# API returning many rows that are exactly the same

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-5, asp.net-web-api

I have two applications:

1. API
2. Web Forms App

I'm using Entity Framework 5 in the API.

The Web Forms App makes an API call and retrieves some data.

For whatever reason, when I get the data back, it's giving me several rows that are exactly the same.

The issue here is that when I use SQL Server Profiler and look at the query, the query is correct and if I take this query and run it in SQL, the results are correct. However, in the Web Forms App, a lot of the data is coming back the same.

Look at these two screenshots -

Running the application:

[image]

Getting the SQL query generated by entity framework and running it into SQL:

[image]

As you can see, this is making me VERY confused...

Does anyone have ANY idea what the issue is here?

Here's my EF model:

[image]

Query generated by Entity Framework:

```
{SELECT 
[Extent1].[dataSource] AS [dataSource], 
[Extent1].[ShowId] AS [ShowId], 
[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent1].[EpisodeId] AS [EpisodeId], 
[Extent1].[EpisodeTitle] AS [EpisodeTitle], 
[Extent1].[Genre] AS [Genre], 
[Extent1].[ShowTypeDescription] AS [ShowTypeDescription], 
[Extent1].[DirectorName] AS [DirectorName], 
[Extent1].[ReleaseYear] AS [ReleaseYear], 
[Extent1].[SeasonEpisode] AS [SeasonEpisode]
FROM (SELECT 
      [TVData_VW_ShowList].[dataSource] AS [dataSource], 
      [TVData_VW_ShowList].[ShowId] AS [ShowId], 
      [TVData_VW_ShowList].[Title] AS [Title], 
      [TVData_VW_ShowList].[EpisodeId] AS [EpisodeId], 
      [TVData_VW_ShowList].[EpisodeTitle] AS [EpisodeTitle], 
      [TVData_VW_ShowList].[Genre] AS [Genre], 
      [TVData_VW_ShowList].[ShowTypeDescription] AS [ShowTypeDescription], 
      [TVData_VW_ShowList].[DirectorName] AS [DirectorName], 
      [TVData_VW_ShowList].[ReleaseYear] AS [ReleaseYear], 
      [TVData_VW_ShowList].[SeasonEpisode] AS [SeasonEpisode]
      FROM [dbo].[TVData_VW_ShowList] AS [TVData_VW_ShowList]) AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Title] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE '~'}
```

I got this query by going into debug mode. If I run it in the actual database, it returns the correct results.

Controller code:

public class ShowsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly TVDataEntities db;

```
public ShowsController()
{
    db = new TVDataEntities();
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
}

public IEnumerable<TVData_VW_ShowList> GetTVData_VW_ShowList(string dataSource = null, string title = null,
                                                             string episodeTitle = null, string genre = null,
                                                             string showTypeDescription = null,
                                                             string directorName = null,
                                                             string releaseYear = null,
                                                             string seasonEpisode = null)
{
    var query = from s in db.TVData_VW_ShowList select s;

    if (dataSource != null)
    {
        if (dataSource != "all")
        {
            query = query.Where(s => s.dataSource.Contains(dataSource));
        }
    }

    if (title != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(title));
    }

    if (episodeTitle != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(s => s.EpisodeTitle.Contains(episodeTitle));
    }

    if (genre != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(s => s.Genre.Contains(genre));
    }

    if (showTypeDescription != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(s => s.ShowTypeDescription.Contains(showTypeDescription));
    }

    if (directorName != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(s => s.DirectorName.Contains(directorName));
    }

    if (releaseYear != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(s => s.ReleaseYear.ToString().Contains(releaseYear));
    }

    if (seasonEpisode != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(s => s.SeasonEpisode.Contains(seasonEpisode));
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

}

Comment: I would debug this step by step.  First start at the source; ignore your Web Forms app and make the API call on your own.  Do you get duplicate data?  Does your collection from the Entity Framework contain the right number of results?

Comment: if I make the API call via the browser it's bringing back the wrong data as well. This is not making any sense to me because the query generated is correct and when run in SQL, returns the correct number of rows...

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in your code (or write to disk or any other debugging method) to verify the results from the Entity Framework?  Basically just verify what EF is returning in comparison to what you might be doing with the result set later in the chain.

Comment: Also, if you do believe it really is EF returning you duplicate records you should post the code where you're fetching the data.

Comment: I added the query that I get from EF in my OP

Comment: I meant the server-side C# code.  If you can verify the raw SQL results are correct in SQL Server, then the issue is not there and it has to be in your code.

Comment: @Ek0nomik, I added the C# code for the controller.

Comment: Does your `IEnumerable` after calling `GetTVData_VW_ShowList` have duplicates or do you end up with duplicates later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved. It was the Linq query.

Here's the correct one:

```
IQueryable<ETSShows> query = from shows in db.ETS_Shows
                                         from episodes in
                                             db.ETS_Episodes.Where(v => v.ShowId == shows.ShowId).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                         from genres in
                                             db.ETS_LKP_Genres.Where(s => s.GenreCode == shows.GenreCode).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                         from showTypes in
                                             db.ETS_LKP_ShowTypes.Where(z => z.ShowTypeCode == shows.ShowTypeCode).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                         from directors in
                                             db.ETS_Directors.Where(p => p.ShowId == shows.ShowId).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                         select new ETSShows
                                             {
                                                 DataSource = "ETS",
                                                 Title = shows.Title,
                                                 EpisodeTitle = episodes.EpisodeTitle,
                                                 Genre = genres.GenreDescription,
                                                 ShowTypeDescription = showTypes.ShowTypeDescription,
                                                 DirectorName = directors.Name,
                                                 ReleaseYear = (int)shows.ReleaseYear,
                                                 SeasonEpisode = episodes.SeasonEpisode,
                                                 ShowId = shows.ShowId,
                                                 EpisodeId = episodes.EpisodeId
                                             };
```